# convert co-ordinate d-m-s to decimal degrees using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

My input is a tab-separated text file with lat long in D-M-S.
I require output to be in decimal degrees
I have code in php, but this is very slow to calculate.
Can this be done quicker using awk?

```
node    name    id  latitude    longitude   seq
nodex   name1   70  N53-24-31.126   W6-20-46.982    59126
nodex   name2   173 N53-20-28.885   W6-14-52.400    16190X
nodex   name3   173 N53-20-28.885   W6-14-52.400    16191T
```

My PHP code with Formula:

```
if ($dirLat == 'N') {$signLat = '+';} Else {$signLat = '-';}
if ($dirLat == 'E') {$signLon = '+';} Else {$signLon = '-';}
$latitudeDecimalDeg = $signLat . ($degLat + ($minLat/60) + ($secLat/3600));
$longitudeDecimalDeg = $signLon . ($degLon + ($minLon/60) + ($secLon/3600));
```

Comment: var names in awk don't use leading `$` signs, and string concatenation doesn't require `.`. Just `longDecDeg = signLon (degLon + (minLon/60) + (secLon/3600))` will be very close. Then a `printf("%4.2fn\n", longDecDeg)`. Good luck.

Comment: that's my php code :)

Comment: It's hard to believe that THAT code is causing your performance problem. Maybe something else in your script, e.g. where you're assigning the variables you use above?

Comment: @EdMorton The table is quite big with over 10k records. Updating it per record using php might be the reason why its slow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty certain that awk would be quicker. This is fairly easily accomplished with awk, split each field with `substr` and `split`. I turned it into a function for easier reuse:

```
function dms2deg(s) {
  dir = (substr(s, 1, 1) ~ /^[NE]/) ? 1 : -1
  dms =  substr(s, 2)
  split(dms, arr, "-")
  return dir * (arr[1] + arr[2]/60 + arr[3]/3600)
}
```

If you have put the above into *dms2deg* and the data is in *infile*, you would use awk like this:

```
awk -f dms2deg -e 'NR>1 { print dms2deg($4), dms2deg($5) }' infile
```

Output:

```
53.4086 -6.34638
53.3414 -6.24789
53.3414 -6.24789
```

Or if you wanted to replace the existing fields:

```
awk -f dms2deg -e 'NR>1 { $4 = dms2deg($4); $5 = dms2deg($5) } $1=$1' infile
```

Output:

```
node name id latitude longitude seq
nodex name1 70 53.4086 -6.34638 59126
nodex name2 173 53.3414 -6.24789 16190X
nodex name3 173 53.3414 -6.24789 16191T
```

Note that this does not preserve white-space, however [`column`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47833/17666) would take care of that:

```
awk -f dms2deg -e 'NR>1 { $4 = dms2deg($4); $5 = dms2deg($5) } $1=$1' infile | column -t
```

Output:

```
node   name   id   latitude  longitude  seq
nodex  name1  70   53.4086   -6.34638   59126
nodex  name2  173  53.3414   -6.24789   16190X
nodex  name3  173  53.3414   -6.24789   16191T
```

Comment: Since the OP is apparently looking for the fastest way to do it, you could save a substr() function call by using `dir = (substr(s, 1, 1) ~ /^[NE]/) ? 1 : -1` instead of `dir = (substr(s, 1, 1) == "N" || substr(s, 1, 1) == "E") ? 1 : -1`.

Comment: thanks. That works well. How do I specify output file on awk -f dms2deg -e 'NR>1 { $4 = dms2deg($4); $5 = dms2deg($5) } $1=$1' infile | column -t

Comment: @SantoshPillai: redirect it to a file with `>`, e.g.: `awk -f dms2deg '...' infile | column -t > outfile`.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't know if it'll be faster or not, but IMHO here's the fastest way you can do it in awk and preserve spacing:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="[- ]+" }
NR>1 {
    sub( $7"-"$8"-"$9, ($7~/^E/?"+":"-") (substr($7,2) + $8/60 + $9/3600) )
    sub( $4"-"$5"-"$6, ($4~/^N/?"+":"-") (substr($4,2) + $5/60 + $6/3600) )
}
1

$ cat file
node    name    id  latitude    longitude   seq
nodex   name1   70  N53-24-31.126   W6-20-46.982    59126
nodex   name2   173 N53-20-28.885   W6-14-52.400    16190X
nodex   name3   173 N53-20-28.885   W6-14-52.400    16191T

$ awk -f tst.awk file
node    name    id  latitude    longitude   seq
nodex   name1   70  +53.4086   -6.34638    59126
nodex   name2   173 +53.3414   -6.24789    16190X
nodex   name3   173 +53.3414   -6.24789    16191T
```

I'd be interested to know if it is faster than your PHP script or not so if you get a chance to compare them, please post the results.

If you don't care about preserving spacing you can just use:

```
BEGIN{ FS="[- ]+" }
NR == 1 { print; next }
{ print $1, $2, $3, ($4~/^N/?"+":"-") (substr($4,2) + $5/60 + $6/3600), ($7~/^E/?"+":"-") (substr($7,2) + $8/60 + $9/3600), $10 }
```

Comment: This solution works as well. However when I output to a file, the result appear all in one line. The file is processed in awk in a few seconds, my php code was taking more than a couple of minutes

Comment: There's no reason for the output of that script to appear all on one line, it prints each line one at a time with the default line terminator for your environment. You mentioned earlier that you're working in Windows, maybe there's some Windows issue, idk.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"[- ]+" 'NR==1 {print;next} {s1=($4~/N/)?1:-1;s2=($7~/E/)?1:-1;print $1,$2,$3,s1*(substr($4,2)+$5/60+$6/3600),s2*(substr($7,2)+$8/60+$9/3600),$10}' file

node    name    id  latitude    longitude   seq
nodex name1 70 53.4086 -6.34638 59126
nodex name2 173 53.3414 -6.24789 16190X
nodex name3 173 53.3414 -6.24789 16191T
```

Comment: I am not seeing same results. My command gawk -F"[- ]+" "NR==1 {print;next} {s1=($4~/N/)?1:-1;s2=($7~/E/)?1:-1;print $1,$2,$3,s1*(substr($4,2)+$5/60+$6/3600),s2*(substr($7,2)+$8/60+$9/3600),$10}" new.txt    node    name    id  latitude    longitude   seq
    nodex name1 70 -19.9383 0
    nodex name2 173 -7.94275 0
    nodex name3 173 -7.94303 0

Comment: You have changed from singe quote `'` to double quote `"` in the awk line.

Comment: I am using awk for windows and it would not work without the change :(

Comment: I created a new file dmsl.awk with the code without single quotes, then I see syntax error. gawk -F"[- ]+" dms.awk file.txt

Answer (score 0):

a quick note on lats and longs - instead of doing 4 divisions each row against fixed constants,

one can streamline it by noticing that the integral component `dd` of the values don't change (other than modifying directions into `+/-` signs),

so instead of divisions, just append a decimal point `.` after `dd`, followed by zero-padding ...

```
floor( ( 60 * mm + ss ) * 277777777777 ) 

                     # or 277777777777.777777777777777777……
```

... out to 15-digits to

```
+53.408646111109966
+53.341356944443488
```