# Convert Wikipedia coordinates ({{coord}}) into decimal

Tags: awk, coordinates, wikipedia, geographic-lib

How can I convert Wikipedia coordinates coming directly from source code into decimal ones?

Input: DMS coordinates

```
{{coord|33|21|30.5|S|70|41|50.4|W|scale:5000}}
```

Desired output:

```
-33.358472, -70.697333
```

Should I use [geoconvert](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/GeoConvert.1.html) or try to do it with awk?

Comment: how would you get "-33.358472" from "33". You can't normally add additional information. only reformat or remove. If the data isn't there and you don't know what it will always be, then you can't really do it.

Comment: DMS to decimal calculation is easy if you have all the values.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood. I'll update with an answer

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

```
D + M/60 + S/3600
```

Is the formular to convert from DMS to Decimal. Have you been able to parse the input to be able to get the DMS values on their own, or is this what you are struggling with?

Comment: I'm now using the PHP parser from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32893821/9468745).

Comment: I'm actually struggling with parsing.